# How to convert month/day and year into mm-dd-yr format

Tags: sql-server

I have one column, `CLTDTD`, that saves the month and day in the following format:

- 102
- 602
- 921
- 827
- 1220

For example, 102 would be January 2nd.

I have another column, `CLTATY`, that saves the year in the following format:

- 1998
- 0
- 1999
- 2003

Both are saved as in numeric format and what I really need is to combine them into an actual `mm-dd-yyyy` formatted date that can show me any records that are within 7 years of today's date (GetDate)

To be more clear about the date range I need. I need all dates that are OLDER than 7 years from today (2006 results and older).

Comment: What you really need is a DB which uses reasonable and properly typed schema. You should change it if possible.

Comment: This is going to be very tricky to do.  How do you know 102 is 1/02 and not 10/2?  You would need to save everything with full digits, ie. 1002 for 10/2.

Comment: @Gramma2005 it's a numeric column, so he likely is using 4 "digits", but the numeric trims off leading 0s. But still: this should be a datetime type. Even formatted strings is just _wrong_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select...

Where DATEDIFF(yy, cast(cast(CLTATY as varchar) + '-' + cast(CLTDTD/100 as varchar) + '-' + cast(CLTDTD%100 as varchar) AS DATETIME), GETDATE()) <= 7

Comment: Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: It must be related to country. In here Cast('2012-01-01' AS DATETIME) computes. Move the date parts around to your specific, for instance 'dd-mm-yyyy', or 'mm-dd-yyyy', instead of 'yyyy-mm-dd'